# Durandaljs pubsub

Tags: events, publish-subscribe, durandal

I would like to ask if there is a way to unsubscribe a specific subscriber using the durandal pubsub mechanism.

For example; Let's say i have the following subscription:

```
app.on('some topic')
    .then(function(){ ... });
```

But when i do:

```
app.off('some topic')
```

it ends up removing all the subscribers for the specific topic.

Instead, i would like to do something the following:

```
 var mySubscriber = function( msg, data ){
      console.log( msg, data );
 };
 var token = PubSub.subscribe( 'MY MESSAGE', mySubscriber );
 PubSub.unsubscribe( token );
```

(The above snippet is taken from the PubSubJs library examples)

Comment: Looking at the source code i found the solution. You just nee to store the callback in a function reference and pass that reference when you want to unsubscribe

Answer (score 3):

```
var subscribeTopic = app.on('some topic')
    .then(function(){ ... });

subscribeTopic.off();
```

http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Leveraging-Publish-Subscribe/